# Are Nagios error messages set somewhere in the configuration or web interface?

Tags: nagios

From what little I know about Nagios, there are little programs that get run on different machines across the network, and they return a status of OK, WARN, or CRITICAL based on a value returned when the program runs and what thresholds have been set for WARN and CRITICAL for the call to the checker.  Do the error messages get set by somebody else configuring that in Nagios or it's web client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thresholds can be passed by arguments or can be fixed directly in the script on your client.
Nagios doesnt store any of these values. Nagios reads these values from the perfdatas sent in the results of the command.
If the thresolds are passed by arguments you can modify them in the concerned service in your nagios conf.